# RInside crash when creating an R instance

Tags: qt, rinside

I tried two examples and they give me the same problem.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qDebug() << "//------- before R instance";
    RInside R(argc, argv);          // create an embedded R instance
    qDebug() << "//------- after R instance";
```

Application output:

```
Starting C:\Users\Alfonso\Desktop\Alf-15\RInside\inst\examples\build-qtdensity-Desktop_Qt_5_4_1_MinGW_32bit-Release\release\qtdensity.exe...
//------- before R instance
The program has unexpectedly finished.
C:\Users\Alfonso\Desktop\Alf-15\RInside\inst\examples\build-qtdensity-Desktop_Qt_5_4_1_MinGW_32bit-Release\release\qtdensity.exe crashed
```

Any ideas? (I work on Windows 7 and I have Qt 5.4.1 MinGW 32bit, R 3.1.3 and RInside 0.2.13)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Qt and R are built with the same (or compatible) versions of MinGW.  If you post on [the rcpp-devel list](http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/mailman/listinfo/rcpp-devel) some other Windows users may be able to help you.

The [example Qt application included in RInside](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rinside/tree/master/inst/examples/qt) still works and does more than this.